# vue-router replace parent view with subRoute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using the vue-router and have a question regarding subRoutes. I would like to set up my routes so the main routes are listings and the subRoutes are things like edit/add/etc.

I want the subRoute components to replace the `<router-view>` of the parent route. The way I understand the documentation and from what I've tested, it looks like I should define another `<router-view>` in the parent components template for the subRoute to render into but then the user-list would remain visible.

Example routes:

```
'/users': {
    name: 'user-list',
    component(resolve) {
        require(['./components/users.vue'], resolve)
    },
    subRoutes: {
        '/add': {
            name: 'add-user',
            component(resolve) {
                require(['./components/users_add.vue'], resolve)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Main router view:

```
<!-- main router view -->
<div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

User list:

```
<template>
    <a v-link="{ name: 'add-user' }">Add</a>
    <ul>
        <li>{{ name }}</li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Add user:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <a v-link="{ name: 'user-list' }">back</a>
        <input type="text" v-model="name">
    </div>
</template>
```

When I click on "Add", I want  to be filled with the add-user template. Is this possible?

Also, can I establish a parent-child relationship between the user-list and add-user components? I would like to be able to pass props (list of users) to the add component and dispatch events back up to the user-list.

Thanks!

Comment: When you go to `/user` the user-list will be rendered in your main view. Automatically when you go `/user/add` il will be rendered in the same `<router-view>`. That's the default behaviour. 

Yes you can have parent-child communication by using props etc.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the default behaviour for me. When I define subRoutes and navigate to them, the root route stays active. When I define the subRoutes as root-level routes, it works :/

Comment: here http://router.vuejs.org/en/nested.html

Comment: That's not very helpful. I read the documentation forwards and backwards. In the *nested* chapter it states "a rendered component can also contain its own, nested `<router-view>`" but [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/map.html) the last example uses `/c` as a container for `<router-view>`. And that's the behaviour I'm seeing as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I played around with this for quite a bit and finally figured out how this can be achieved. The trick is to make the listing a subRoute too and have the root-level route just offer a `<router-view>` container for all child components to render into. Then, move the "list loading" stuff to the parent component and pass the list to the list-component as a prop. You can then tell the parent to reload the list via events.

That's it for now, it works like a charm. Only drawback is that I have another component that I didn't really need. I'll follow up with an example when I find the time.

**edit**

Added an example as requested. Please note: this code is from 2016 - it may not work with current Vue versions. They changed the event system so parent/child communication works differently. It is now considered bad practice to communicate in both directions (at least the way I'm doing it here). Also, these days I would solve this differently and give each route it's own module in the store.

That said, here's the example I would have added back in 2016:
Let's stick with the users example - we have a page with which you can list/add/edit users.

Here's the route definition:

```
'/users': {
    name: 'users',
    component(resolve) {
        // this is what I meant with "root-level" route, it acts as a parent to the sub routes
        require(['./pages/users.vue'], resolve)
    },
    subRoutes: {
        '/': {
            name: 'user-list',
            component(resolve) {
                require(['./pages/users/list.vue'], resolve)
            }
        },
        '/add': {
            name: 'user-add',
            component(resolve) {
                require(['./pages/users/add.vue'], resolve)
            }
        },
        // etc.
    }
},
```

users.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <router-view :users="users"></router-view>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
/**
 * This component acts as a parent and sort of state-storage for
 * all user child components. It's the route that's loaded at /users.
 * the list component is the actual component that is shown though, but since
 * that's a sibling of the other child components, we need this.
 */
export default {
  events: {
    /**
    * Update users when child says so
    */
    updateUsers() {
      this.loadUsers();
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      users: []
    }
  },

  route: {
    data() {
      // load users from server
      if (!this.users.length) {
        this.loadUsers();
      }
    }
  },

  methods: {
    loadUsers() {
      // load the users from an API or something
      this.users = response.data;
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

./pages/users/list.vue

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
      {{ user.name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['users'],
  // the rest of the component
}
</script>
```

Comment: Those "wrapper" components are quite common in these scenarios. In the React community, they are called "smart" components (who know about external data, and manipulate it) who provide the data for other components.

Might seem tedious now but it's useful.

Comment: @Christof could you please share some code to explain your answer? Thanks!

Comment: @PavelKovalev added the example. Please also read the disclaimer :)

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like those edit/add routes should not be subRoutes, simple as that.

just because the path makes it seem like nesting doesn't mean you have to actually nest them.

```
'/users': {
    name: 'user-list',
    component(resolve) {
      require(['./components/users.vue'], resolve)
    }
},
'users/add': {
    name: 'add-user',
    component(resolve) {
      require(['./components/users_add.vue'], resolve)
    }
}
```

Comment: That was what I did first. The problem is that there is no parent-child relationship established so you cannot pass data between them via props or events.

Comment: There's no way to pass data with props if you could replace the parent with it's child route, either.

You should think about having a centralized store.

Comment: That's probably true. I did think about adding a centralized storage but this is more a traditional "admin panel" kind of web app and I really don't these listings throughout the whole app, just from the list to the add/edit view and back. The solution I posted above works quite well for this. Thanks for your thoughts.